# Is there a way to get the number and name of Item responses on a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form, I use `getItemResponses` and check each response with the reference `itemResponses[0].getResponse()`. This works great when the google form questions are all required, I can predict what each question pertains to. Now I want some questions to be optional, so when I use my script to read the replies it crashes because I reference something out of bounds to the array.

Question . Can I loop through all the responses and tell which question the response is for?

Comment: You could check for their truthyness before trying to access them.  All of the questions have columns in the linked spreadsheet.  There's two onFormSubmit triggers one for the form and one for the spreadsheet.  Do some research.

Comment: itemResponses is an array object, so just loop over the array. If you don't know how to do that, just Google the `Array` object under Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) documentation for Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to can check the item/question's title and assign its answer to the variable you want to hold its value.

#### Sample form:

[image: sample form]

#### Code:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponse = e.response;
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  var fullName, favoriteFood, question, answer, itemResponse;
  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    answer = itemResponse.getResponse();
    if(question == "full name") { // required
      fullName = answer;
    }
    else if(question == "favorite food") { // optional
      favoriteFood = answer;
    }
  }
  Logger.log("your full name is: " + fullName);
  
  if (favoriteFood) // optional, print if answered
    Logger.log("your favorite food is: " + favoriteFood);
}
```

#### Note:

- Make sure to add `myFunction` as a trigger `on form submit`
- If you have a lot of questions, use `switch-case` instead of multiple if statements.

[image: note]

#### Output:

- When you submit a response, the code above will check the question title. If it matches, then it assigns the `answer` value into the variable you want to hold that value. This way, you won't worry about any issue about array `out of bounds`

[image: output]

Comment: Thks so simple... I guess I should RTFM I need to take some training courses, Any recommendations?

Comment: Hi @PeterMacDonaldSykes, glad the answer was acceptable for you. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. As for the training courses, I am not promoting this in any way but found this one and enrolled on it as it was free. Feel free to try this [one](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script-course/).